# A question about Pinocchio's nose

Tags: logical-deduction, paradox

What happens to Pinocchio's nose if he says to another person "My nose is about to grow"?

Does it grow?

Does it stay the same?

Something else?

Comment: The problem is that you have not defined the terms. For us to answer, you have to precisely define a lie. Otherwise we can invent our own definition (as in the answer by Gordon K). We also need to know how long 'about to' refers to. Maybe Pinnochio intends to tell a deliberate lie after he said that. You cannot tell us that there was no gap between him speaking and his nose reacting -- maybe his nose just waits to see if he will tell a lie after making the statement.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that Pinnochio's nose only grows when he tells a lie, not if he makes a mistake, so what happens with his nose depends upon what he believes.

- If he thinks that his nose really is about to grow, then he is not lying, his nose will not grow but he will have made a mistake.
- If he thinks that his nose is not about to grow, then he is lying and his nose will grow.

In either case there is no paradox.